How to bulk remove trivial if statements
I'm working on refactoring a big codebase and part of the refactor includes removing some checks. I couldn't figure out a way to do this efficiently.  For example if the old code was something like:
if A:
  print("branch 1")
else:
  print("branch 2")

I want to delete A and make it always True. So my new code would look something like:
if True:
  print("branch 1")
else:
  print("branch 2") # unreachable

Now I want to simplify the code into:
print("branch 1")

A few different scenarios that complicate this:
Scenario 1:
if A and B:
  print("branch 1")
else:
  print("branch 2")

would become:
if B:
  print("branch 1")
else:
  print("branch 2")

Scenario 2:
if A:
  print("branch 1")
  return
print("branch 2")

would become:
print("branch 1")
  return

I couldn't figure out a way to do it efficiently. I tried running a few different linters to see if any of them would suggest the simplification, but got no luck. I am also not good enough doing codemods to write my own script 

you can chose a default thing like, branch = default_branch, if condition: branch = condition_branch and then can proceed further

Just how many do you need to change? It make take longer to find a way to do it correctly than it would to just make the changes manually. These kinds of code transformations don't necessarily arise often enough to be worth automating.

Pyrefact appears to do this sort of thing and much more. Before I remembered that this tool exists, however, I wrote some code that only does what you describe. Below is the answer I wrote at that time.
This can be achieved using Python's AST module. The following code will replace all instances of the variable A with True (this can be modified/extended using the VARS variable) and will also simplify boolean expressions (e.g., if True and X: becomes if X:) and trivial if statements (removing cases that will obviously never run). To apply it to a file called file.py, save this code in a file (which I will assume is called if_simplifier.py and is in the same directory) and run the following from the command line:
python if_simplifier.py file.py

Two Caveats:

While I tested this code on several relevant examples, it's possible I missed an important edge case, so make sure any reformatted code looks correct, and ensure that you test the new code to make sure things are still functional.
While the way ast.unparse() works guarantees that indentation won't be bad, this code doesn't remove unreachable code (like the print("branch 2") from your Scenario 2), and it does remove some spacing/formatting that will make the resulting code slightly less readable. You can detect unreachable code manually or with a tool like Vulture, and you can reformat your code with a tool like Black (which is also available as an extension for VS Code) to restore readability.

import ast
import sys
from typing import Any

VARS = {"A": True}


class Visitor(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, variables: dict[str, Any] | None = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.variables = variables or {}

    def visit_Name(self, node: ast.Name) -> ast.AST:
        self.generic_visit(node)
        if node.id in self.variables:
            return ast.Constant(value=self.variables[node.id])
        return node

    def visit_If(self, node: ast.If) -> ast.AST | list[ast.stmt]:
        self.generic_visit(node)
        if isinstance(node.test, ast.Constant):
            if node.test.value:
                return node.body
            else:
                return node.orelse
        return node

    def visit_UnaryOp(self, node: ast.UnaryOp) -> ast.AST:
        self.generic_visit(node)
        if isinstance(node.op, ast.Not) and isinstance(node.operand, ast.Constant):
            return ast.Constant(value=not node.operand.value)
        return node

    def visit_BoolOp(self, node: ast.BoolOp) -> ast.AST:
        self.generic_visit(node)
        if isinstance(node.op, ast.Or):
            new_values = []
            for value in node.values:
                if isinstance(value, ast.Constant):
                    if value.value:
                        return value
                else:
                    new_values.append(value)
            if len(new_values) == 0:
                return ast.Constant(value=False)
            elif len(new_values) == 1:
                return new_values[0]
            else:
                node.values = new_values
        elif isinstance(node.op, ast.And):
            new_values = []
            for value in node.values:
                if isinstance(value, ast.Constant):
                    if not value.value:
                        return value
                else:
                    new_values.append(value)
            if len(new_values) == 0:
                return ast.Constant(value=True)
            elif len(new_values) == 1:
                return new_values[0]
            else:
                node.values = new_values
        return node


def simplify_ifs(code: str, variables: dict[str, Any] | None = None) -> str:
    tree = ast.parse(code)
    visitor = Visitor(variables=variables)
    visitor.visit(tree)
    return ast.unparse(tree)


def main():
    path = sys.argv[1]
    code = ""
    with open(path, "r") as f:
        code = f.read()
    with open(path, "w") as f:
        f.write(simplify_ifs(code, variables=VARS))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

